# Bootstrap 4 Popovers don't work in Wordpress Understrap theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I'm currently using the Understrap child theme in Wordpress. I can't get popovers, tooltips or vertical pills to work.

Here is a live example: [Sample Page](https://arondomains.com/sample-page/)

Popper.js seems to be included with the child theme. Any suggestions? I'm not sure what is the missing puzzle.

I'm using understrap documentation from GitHub and using [parent](https://github.com/understrap/understrap) and understrap [child theme](https://github.com/understrap/understrap-child) files as they are.

Comment: Tooltips working for me.. What browser are you on?

Comment: @Paddymac thanks for your prompt reply. Won't work for me, must be a missing puzzle. Vertical pills arent vertical neither. [link](https://arondomains.com/sample-page/)

Comment: What documentation are you following?

Comment: Add your JavaScript to your question please.

Comment: I've followed understrap documentation from [github](https://github.com/understrap/understrap) and used their files for both parent and [understrap child theme](https://github.com/understrap/understrap-child)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with the latest understrap theme and the child. understrap seems to have removed poppers.js. From the changelog:
- Using bootstrap.bundle.js instead of bootstrapjs and popper.js

https://github.com/understrap/understrap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

But the understrap child didn't...

Here is a discussion about it and possible solution:
https://github.com/understrap/understrap-child/issues/195